# Haskell - Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'

Tags: haskell

I currently have the following code in Haskell

```
splitStringOnDelimeter :: String -> Char -> [String]

splitStringOnDelimeter "" delimeter = return [""]

splitStringOnDelimeter string delimeter = do
    let split = splitStringOnDelimeter (tail string) delimeter
    if head string == delimeter
    then return ([""] ++ split)
    else return ( [( [(head string)] ++ (head split) )] ++ (tail split))
```

If I run it in a Haskell terminal (i.e. https://www.tryhaskell.org) with values for the return statement such as `( [( [(head "ZZZZ")] ++ (head ["first", "second", "third"]) )] ++ (tail ["first", "second", "third"]))` or `[""] ++ ["first", "second", "third"]` or `[""]` then I receive the correct types from the terminal which is different to my local stack compiler. Furthermore, if I also change the top return statement to `return ""` then it doesn't complain about that statement which I'm pretty sure is incorrect.

My local compiler works fine with the rest of my Haskell codebase which is why I think it might be something wrong with my code...

Comment: A little note, don't use tryhaskell.org, it's very limited. A better online REPL is avaiable at [repl.it](https://www.repl.it/languages/haskell), and elsewhere.

Comment: the type errors privide location information, and more info which would help to understand the issue without reproducing it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the unfortunate things in the design of the `Monad` typeclass, is that they introduced a *function* called `return`. But although in many imperative programming languages `return` is a keyword to return content, in Haskell `return` has a totally different meaning, it does *not* really return something.

You can solve the problem by dropping the `return`:

```
splitStringOnDelimeter :: String -> Char -> [String]
splitStringOnDelimeter "" delimeter = [""]
splitStringOnDelimeter string delimeter =
    let split = splitStringOnDelimeter (tail string) delimeter in
    if head string == delimeter
    then ([""] ++ split)
    else ( [( [(head string)] ++ (head split) )] ++ (tail split))
```

The `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` is used to wrap a value (of type `a`) in a monad. Since here your signature hints about a list, Haskell will assume that you look for the list monad. So that means that you `return` would wrap `[""]` into another list, so implicitly with `return [""]` you would have written (in this context), `[[""]]`, and this of course does *not* match with `[String]`.

The same goes for `do`, again you them make a monadic function, but here your function has not much to do with monads.

Note that the name `return` is not *per se* bad, but since nearly all imperative languages attach an (almost) equivalent meaning to it, most people assume that it works the same way in functional languages, but it does not.

Mind that you use functions like `head`, `tail`, etc. These are usually seen as anti-patterns: you can use pattern matching instead. We can rewrite this to:

```
splitStringOnDelimeter :: String -> Char -> [String]
splitStringOnDelimeter "" delimeter = [""]
splitStringOnDelimeter (h:t) delimeter | h == delimeter = "" : split
                                       | otherwise = (h : sh) : st
    where split@(sh:st) = splitStringOnDelimeter t delimeter
```

By using pattern matching, we know for sure that the `string` has a head `h` and a tail `t`, and we can directly use these into the expression. This makes the expression shorter as well as more readable. Although `if`-`then`-`else` clauses are not per se anti-patterns, personally I think guards are syntactically more clean. We thus use a `where` clause here where we call `splitStringOnDelimter t delimeter`, and we pattern match this with `split` (as well as with `(sh:st)`. We know that this will always match, since both the basecase and the inductive case always produce a list with at least one element. This again allows use to write a neat expression where we can use `sh` and `st` directly, instead of calling `head` and `tail`.

If I test this function locally, I got:

```
Prelude> splitStringOnDelimeter "foo!bar!!qux" '!'
["foo","bar","","qux"]
```

As *take-away message*, I think you better avoid using `return`, and `do`, unless you know what this function and keyword (`do` is a keyword) really mean. In the context of functional programming these have a different meaning.

Comment: Going along with that, what I've started recommending (for people who have a sufficiently new version of `ghc`) is to simply never use `return`, and when you actually do need a monadic unit, use `pure`, which does the same thing without the unfortunate naming implications.

Answer (score 0):

`return` has type `forall m a. Monad m => a -> m a`. 
The output type of the function `splitStringOnDelimiter` is `[String]`, so if you try to write some output value using `return`, the compiler will infer that you want to provide some `m a`, thus instantiating `m` to `[]` (which is indeed an instance of the Monad typeclass), and `a` to `String`. It follows that the compiler will now expect some `String` to be used as argument of `return`. This expectation is violated in, for example, `return ([""] ++ split)`, because here the argument of `return`, namely `[""] ++ split` has type `[String]` rather than `String`.

`do` is used as a convenient notation for monadic code, so you should rely on it only if you are interested in using the monadic operations of the output type. In this case, you really just want to manipulate lists using pure functions.

I'll add my 2 cents and suggest a solution. I used a `foldr`, that is a simple instance of a [recursion scheme](http://blog.sumtypeofway.com/an-introduction-to-recursion-schemes/). Recursion schemes like `foldr` capture common patterns of computation; they make recursive definitions clear, easy to reason about, and *total* by construction.

I also took advantage of the fact that the output list is always *non-empty*, so I wrote it in the type. By being more precise about my intentions, I now know that `split`, the result of the recursive call, is a `NonEmpty String`, so I can use the *total* functions `head` and `tail` (from `Data.List.NonEmpty`), because a non-empty list has *always* a head and a tail.

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty as NE (NonEmpty(..), (<|), head, tail)

splitStringOnDelimeter :: String -> Char -> NonEmpty String
splitStringOnDelimeter string delimiter = foldr f (pure "") string
  where f h split = if h == delimiter 
                      then ("" <| split) 
                      else (h : NE.head split) :| NE.tail split
```